# Android Studio with Google Calendar API V3

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I wanted to try out google calendar API v3. I have Android Studio 1.0. I created a java endpoint module from Android Studio. I was following the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get)

If you follow the link I provided, you will see a line like this

```
Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
    .setApplicationName("applicationName").build();
```

Now what will be the `httpTransport`, `jsonfactory` and `credentials` here? Official documentation did not specify anything.

I also followed a sample in java from [here](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-appengine-sample/instructions.html).

This was done using Java Servlet and Eclipse. I am not familiar with that. It wont work on Android Studio.

Can anyone provide me a sample? or any direction to work with Calender API and Android Studio? Or what to do in the official sample mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `GoogleAccountCredential` as the last argument

```
GoogleAccountCredential googleAccountCredential =
     GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(context, "server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID);
     googleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName(userEmail);
```

What is `WEB_CLIENT_ID` you can find in many tutorials over the internet. It's basically ID which you can generate using Google Developers Console for given project.

Here's how to create `Calendar` instance with transport and JSON factory.

```
new Calendar.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            AndroidJsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), googleAccountCredential);
```